# How do I save scraped data from multiple pages in Pandas Dataframe correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have written a webscraper which will scrape multiple webpage products of the same website(by same website I mean website as ebay.com and multiple webpage products mean ebay.com/perfumes, ebay.com/cameras). I am trying to save the scraped data in the form of a csv file for which I am using Pandas dataframe. I am able to print the data on my Terminal but this data is being printed seperately,I want this to be printed together. As well as the data that is being saved in the csv file is the most recent data,thereby not saving the first set of data.
Here is the code for the webscraper and I have created a dataframe and saved it in a csv file as well.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pandas as pd


def scrape_products():
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'Price', 'Condition', 'Category', 'Item No', 'EAN', 'Postage', 'RRP'])
    website_address = [
        'https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/The-Discworld-series-Carpe-jugulum-by-Terry-Pratchett-Paperback-Amazing-Value/293566021594?hash=item4459e5ffda:g:yssAAOSw3NBfQ7I0',
        'https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Edexcel-AS-A-level-history-Germany-and-West-Germany-1918-89-by-Barbara/293497601580?hash=item4455d1fe2c:g:6lYAAOSwbRFeXGqL']
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('start-maximized')
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)

    browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
    for web in website_address:
        browser.get(web)
        time.sleep(2)

        product_price_raw_list = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="vi-mskumap-none"]').text
        product_name_raw_lst = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="itemTitle"]').text
        product_condition = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="vi-itm-cond"]').text
        product_category = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="vi-VR-brumb-lnkLst"]/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li[1]').text
        product_ebay_item_no = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="descItemNumber"]').text
        product_ean = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="viTabs_0_is"]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]').text
        product_postage = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="shSummary"]').text
        product_rrp = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.actPanel  div div:nth-child(2) span')
        if product_rrp:  # has results
            print(product_rrp[0].text)
        else:
            print('no rpp')
        # return product_price_raw_list, product_name_raw_lst, product_condition, product_category, product_ebay_item_no, product_ean, product_postage, product_rrp

        data_frame = pd.DataFrame([[product_price_raw_list, product_name_raw_lst, product_condition, product_category, product_ebay_item_no, product_ean, product_postage, product_rrp]], columns=['Name', 'Price', 'Condition', 'Category', 'Item No', 'EAN', 'Postage', 'RRP'])
        final_df = df.append(data_frame, ignore_index=True)
        final_df.to_csv('saving_scraped.csv', index=False)
        print(final_df.head())
        print('END.')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    scrape_products()
```

This is what my output on the terminal looks like:

```
[WDM] - Driver [/home/user/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/74.0.3729.6/chromedriver] found in cache
Was:
£7.99
    Name                                              Price  ...                              Postage                                                RRP
0  £4.99  The Discworld series: Carpe jugulum by Terry P...  ...  Doesn't post to India | See details  [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElem...

[1 rows x 8 columns]
END.
£6.68
    Name                                              Price  ...                              Postage                                                RRP
0  £6.68  Edexcel AS/A-level history. Germany and West G...  ...  Doesn't post to India | See details  [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElem...

[1 rows x 8 columns]
END.
```

And here is the saved data in my csv file.

```
Name,Price,Condition,Category,Item No,EAN,Postage,RRP
£6.68,"Edexcel AS/A-level history. Germany and West Germany, 1918-89 by Barbara",Good,"Books, Comics & Magazines",293497601580,9781471876493,Doesn't post to India | See details,"[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session=""35378d132e0de972988548942dd94321"", element=""0.28667503759225554-8"")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session=""35378d132e0de972988548942dd94321"", element=""0.28667503759225554-9"")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session=""35378d132e0de972988548942dd94321"", element=""0.28667503759225554-10"")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session=""35378d132e0de972988548942dd94321"", element=""0.28667503759225554-11"")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session=""35378d132e0de972988548942dd94321"", element=""0.28667503759225554-12"")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session=""35378d132e0de972988548942dd94321"", element=""0.28667503759225554-13"")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session=""35378d132e0de972988548942dd94321"", element=""0.28667503759225554-14"")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session=""35378d132e0de972988548942dd94321"", element=""0.28667503759225554-15"")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session=""35378d132e0de972988548942dd94321"", element=""0.28667503759225554-16"")>]"
```

How do I ensure that the data which I want to print on my terminal and save in my csv file should be like

```
Name,Price,Condition,Category,Item No,EAN,Postage,RRP
abc,12,good,movies,jno,987,2343,USA,9dollars
xyz,13,very good,scifi,ojk,7675,990,NZ,19Pounds
```

Where am I making an error,I do not get it. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this line

```
        final_df = df.append(data_frame, ignore_index=True)
```

should be replaced with

```
        final_df = final_df.append(data_frame, ignore_index=True)
```

so you add `data_frame` to what you have collected on the previous iterations of the loop rather than overwriting them

also you should probably take these lines

```
        final_df.to_csv('saving_scraped.csv', index=False)
        print(final_df.head())
        print('END.')
```

out of the loop as you do not need to save `final_df` on each iteration

If you want to monitor progress as the loop goes through different pages, you can replace the print statement in the loop with

```
       print(data_frame.head())
```

so you print whatever was scraped on that iteration rather than `final_df` that has all the results aggregated

Comment: Hi, I tried working with this..I have a list of 75 such websites..so it should save all 75 records..but its only saving 15 records in the dataframe.

Comment: @technophile_3 so it sounds to me that your original problem is solved as you get more than one (15) websites in your dataframe. You now have a separate issue which is the other 60 websites are probably returning empty dataframe. That could happen for various reasons eg their websites are slightly different? You should take one of them and debug your code through that. This is, however, a separate question

Comment: So the other 60 websites are the same..ie theyre something like ebay.com/tshirts, ebay.com/jeans ebay.com/dumbells, ebay.com/cricketbat etc. I am not getting it. it is being printed on the terminal but not getting saved in the csv file